# Not getting a result with single sign on to Goodreads on Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, oauth, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I am trying to sign in with goodreads. 
I am calling the WebAuthenticationBroker, which opens an overlay to log in. This works so far, but I can't get the overlay to close after the login. I am also not getting a success result. When using the backarrow however I get a "UserCanceled" result.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
string goodreadsURL = "https://www.goodreads.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=" + Properties.OAuth_token;

Uri sid = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri();
string callbackURL = sid.ToString();

var startUri = new Uri(goodreadsURL);

WebAuthenticationResult result = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, startUri, new Uri(callbackURL));
if (result.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success && !result.ResponseData.Contains("&error="))
{
    [...]
}
```

I found a similar question [Cannot get Facebook single signon with windows 8.1 to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030744/cannot-get-facebook-single-signon-with-windows-8-1-to-work), but the suggested answer is not working for my case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that might indicate the OAuth callback URL wasn't being navigated to and from the code it seems like it wasn't specified. You might need to add it. Try this:

```
string goodreadsURL =
    "https://www.goodreads.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=" + Properties.OAuth_token;

Uri sid = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri();
string callbackURL = sid.ToString();

var startUri =
    new Uri(goodreadsURL + "&oauth_callback=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(callbackURL));

WebAuthenticationResult result =
    await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
        WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
        startUri,
        new Uri(callbackURL));

if (result.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success &&
    !result.ResponseData.Contains("&error="))
{
    [...]
}
```

Check the docs mentioning callbacks here:
https://www.goodreads.com/api/documentation